# split the source of images depending upon selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, src, onselect

What is the best way to load images from two separate sources depending upon users selection, in this case selection of dates? Is it possible to have 2 different src paths dependent on conditions? Any advice would be appreciated. Here's the relevant code:

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
$("#img").attr("src", "myimagesrc" + dateText + ".jpg");
```

Comment: What would be the value of `dateText`? and how do you want to `split` it? Please post a sample output of `src` and the value of `dateText`.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I need 2 src for images depending on if date is chosen before or after 2010. The dateText will return "yy-mm-dd". How do I add a second src based on those conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't. What you do is you parse dateText, check - in your case the year - and *then* set the src attribute.